# iOS Swift - Virgil Security user is already registered - private key not found

Tags: encryption, private-key

**Context**

When using the Virgil Security SDK for iOS swift after authenticating "Alice" and fetching a JWT token, upon registration an error always states that a user is already registered. This happens on first login even after clearing a device or using a new device. Further more when trying the `eThree.authEncrypt()` method for text an error always states that a private key is not found on the device, even though `eThree.hasPrivateKey()` is returning true.

**Code Tried**

```
        do {
            let params = try EThreeParams(identity: "Alice", tokenCallback: self.virgil.authWithVirgil)
            let ethree = try EThree(params: params)

            ethree.register { error in
                guard error == nil else {
                    // Error handling here
                    print(error?.localizedDescription) //User is already registered
                    return
                }
                print("New Registration")
                // User private key loaded, ready to end-to-end encrypt!
            }

        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

**Questions**

- Why after clearing a device or using a new device does the code tell me that a user is already registered?
- Why does  `hasPrivateKey` return true but then when using `authEncrypt` there is an error saying there it no private key in the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Q1

> Why after clearing a device or using a new device does the code tell me that a user is already registered?

Short answer: There is no local private key within a cleared device or within a new device.

From [the official documentation](https://developer.virgilsecurity.com/docs/e3kit/user-authentication/).

> The EThree.register() function checks whether a user already has a private key saved in local storage, and a published public key on the Virgil Cloud. If the user doesn't have them, the function generates a new keypair for the user, saves the private key locally...

### Q2

> Why does `hasPrivateKey` return true but then when using `authEncrypt` there is an error saying there it no private key in the device?

`LocalKeyStorage.retrieveKeyPair()` can be used to define private key presence.

### Best practice

To support login across multiple-devices [Key Backup](https://developer.virgilsecurity.com/docs/e3kit/key-backup/) mechanism can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Q1

> Why after clearing a device or using a new device does the code tell
> me that a user is already registered?

`Registered` is not related to the presence of a private key. One user can only have one private key. Once it has been registered to one device it cannot be used in other devices without having made a backup to Virgil Cloud when first adding a user to a device.

Once a user has a [private key](https://developer.virgilsecurity.com/docs/e3kit/key-backup/) on one device they can't have a private key on other devices except by fetching the private through Virgil Cloud with a password, or by calling `eThree.rotatePrivateKey()`.